# jquery and php : how to load certain div item only on click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load, lazy-loading

I know how to toggle a certain div item on click, but what if I don't want a certain item to load yet? Not just hide in the page, but do not load it until it is clicked?

I know that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item').click(function(){
          $('#item2').toggle();
   });
});
```

will load everything and #item2 will be hidden only until clicked, but I don't want the item to hide, I don't want it to load until clicked. I'm doing this because if I have a lot of large files, it will slow the page. is there anyway to do this: click #item, then load #item2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a separate file containing the content of the div (in this example, pagesource.php), and then use asynchronous loading with AJAX. See [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$('#item').click( function() {
    // Load page the first time it is clicked (assuming the inner HTML of the div is blank)
    if( $('#item2').html() == '' ) {
        $.get( 'pagesource.php', function(data) {
            $('#item2').html(data);
        });
    }
    $('#item2').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this one helped me the most. But did you mean those should be item2?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice the two separate divs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Ajax to do this.  When the user clicks, load the content asynchronously and when it's done loading then show it.

Answer (score 0):

Definetely you can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item').click(function(){
          //This line will create 'item2' div dynamically
          $('<div id="item2" />').hide().appendTo("body").toggle();
   });
});
```

If you want to check if it exists, here you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item').click(function(){              
          $item2 = $("#item2");
          if($item2.size() == 0) //Will create item2 if it doesn't exist
             $item2 = $('<div id="item2" />').hide().appendTo("body");
          $item2.toggle();
   });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers